# Select input only select one value using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So far, my code binds data to `choices` object, and then add field input dynamically when clicking "add course" button. Then, uses `$http.get` to return json data from the server and binds it to select option. Although when I choose an option, it only selects applied option.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="timeTable" ng-controller="addCoursesCtrl">
  <button ng-click="addNewCourse()">Add New Course</button>

  <fieldset ng-repeat="choice in choices">

    <select ng-model="choice.type" 
            ng-options="s.value as s.name for s in coursetoAdd">
      <option value="{{s.value}}">{{s.value}}</option>
    </select>

    <input ng-model="choice.course">

  </fieldset>
  <button ng-click="convertAndSend()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var timeTable = angular.module("timeTable",[]);
timeTable.controller("addCoursesCtrl", function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.choices = [{ course: '', type: '' }];
    $scope.coursetoAdd = $scope.choices;

    $http.get("/Semster/getSuggtedCourses").then(function (response) {
        $scope.coursetoAdd = response.data;
    });
    $scope.addNewCourse = function () {
        var newITemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        $scope.choices.push({ course: '', type: '' });
    };
    $scope.convertAndSend = function () {
        var asJson = angular.toJson($scope.choices);
        console.log(asJson);
        $http.post('/Semster/Add', asJson);
    };

});
```

Comment: Remove `<option value="{{s.value}}">{{s.value}}</option>`.

Comment: @dfsq ,I removed it ,still not working

Comment: @theprogrammer_man, i read your question 5 times and I still don't understand what the problem you are facing. try to reproduce in a plunk. specify exactly what you expect. Also, why are you reassigning `$scope.coursetoAdd` from what it was assigned statically to whatever is returned? What is the reason for the first assignment?